# How to create a folder in C (need to run on both Linux and Windows)

Tags: c, linux, windows, directory, create-directory

I don't have much experience and I'm on a C project where I need to create & delete folders and the program must run on both Linux and Windows.

I saw few solutions but all were either for Windows or Linux but none for both and most uses system(...).

Also, if there is an easy way to delete a folder with it's contents, I'm interrested (for the moment I delete each files one by one and then the folder with remove(...))
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `pragma #ifdef` to switch between fucntions for linux and windows, and also includes according to platform

Comment: This question is two questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a common 'create directory' method:

```
void make_directory(const char* name) 
   {
   #ifdef __linux__
       mkdir(name, 777); 
   #else
       _mkdir(name);
   #endif
   }
```

As for removing directories, you are on the right track, ie:

> for the moment I delete each files one by one and then the folder with remove(...)

Comment: Seems to work despite a "warning implicit declaration of mkdir". and it seems like I don't have right on the new folder. I'll look into it more deeply, thanks.

Comment: A "default" umask of `777` is not nice.

Comment: @Aleksandair You need to include <dirent.h>.

Answer (score 1):

It is not what you should do in production code, but I had to mention that one liner solution no `#ifdef` etc. I am Assuming you run it from the same path you want to create the directory in:

```
system("mkdir my_dir");
```

Answer (score -9):

As I know, you can use the `cd` (change directory) command to create folder. You can use the `rmdir` command to delete empty directories. If you want to delete the directory with its contents,  use `rm -rf name-of-the-directory`. The `-rf` specifies to force the deletion and to do it recursively.

You can use these using the command line, but if you want to do this programmatically, I'd say that PHP is suitable to do such.

Comment: You cannot use `cd` to create a directory, it's a navigation-only command! You'd use `mkdir` instead.

Comment: Also, **please** read [this resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on formatting; I've noticed that each of your answers has bad formatting, and it detracts heavily from how an answer is perceived.