# Can't find mkdir() function in dirent.h for windows

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mkdir, dirent.h

I am using dirent.h 1.20 ([source](http://www.softagalleria.net/download/dirent/?C=M;O=D)) for windows in VC2013.

I can't find `mkdir()` in it.

How am I supposed to use it? Or can I create a directory somehow only using dirent.h?

Comment: `mkdir` isn't supposed to live in `<dirent.h>`. On POSIX systems, you get it from `<sys/types.h>` and `<sys/stat.h>` (yes, you need both).

Comment: If boost is an option for you: It has a [file system library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), which offers the same functionality in a portable way.

Comment: You have [_mkdir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw(v=vs.100).aspx) as part of the C library. So unless you need something else out of that other library, you don't need it for creating a directory (`#include <direct.h>`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a folder in C (need to run on both Linux and Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271990/how-to-create-a-folder-in-c-need-to-run-on-both-linux-and-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Since C++17, [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) is the portable way to go. For earlier compilers, check out [Boost.Filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

---

The header you are linking to is effectively turning your (POSIX) `dirent.h` calls into (native) Windows calls. But `dirent.h` is about **dir**ectory **ent**ries, i.e. *reading* directories, not *creating* ones.

If you want to *create* a directory (`mkdir()`), you need either:

- A similar wrapping header turning your (POSIX) `mkdir()` call into the corresponding (native) Windows function calls (and I cannot point out such a header for you), or
- use the [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly, which might be pragmatic but would lead to a really ugly mix of POSIX and Windows functions...

---

```
// UGLY - these two don't belong in the same source...
#include <dirent.h>
#include <windows.h>

// ...
CreateDirectory( "D:\\TestDir", NULL );
// ...
```

---

Another solution would be to take a look at [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), which provides a POSIX environment running on Windows, including Bash shell, GCC compiler toolchain, and a complete collection of POSIX headers like `dirent.h`, `sys/stat.h`, `sys/types.h` etc., allowing you to use the POSIX API consistently in your programming.

Answer (score 16):

simplest way that helped without using any other library is.

```
#if defined _MSC_VER
#include <direct.h>
#elif defined __GNUC__
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#endif

void createDir(string dir) {
#if defined _MSC_VER
    _mkdir(dir.data());
#elif defined __GNUC__
    mkdir(dir.data(), 0777);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio includes the `<direct.h>` header.
This header declares [_mkdir and _wmkdir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw(v=vs.120).aspx), which can be used to create a directory, and are part of the C libraries included with Visual Studio.

The other "easy" option would be to use Windows API calls as indicated by [DevSolar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23427935/1441).

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys/types.h header file and use
`mkdir(const char*)` method to create a directory
Following is the sample code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    if(!mkdir("C:mydir"))
    {
        printf("File created\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Error\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that [Microsoft say the \[mkdir\] POSIX function is deprecated. Use the ISO C++ conformant _mkdir instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mkdir): "

Answer (score 0):

mkdir is deprecated. Give `#include <direct.h>` as a header file. then write

```
_mkdir("C:/folder")
```