# How to create a folder in C

Tags: c, directory

How can I create a new folder for an email manager, I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
void create_folder() {
    int check;
    char *dirname;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a directory path and name to create a folder (C:/name):");
    gets(dirname);
    check = mkdir(dirname);

    if (!check)
        printf("Folder created\n");
    else {
        printf("Unable to create folder\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    getch();
    system("dir/p");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work how? Compiler error? Crashes? Computer catches on fire?

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `dirname` to point to, so you've got undefined behavior at `gets(dirname)`. Also, `gets()` is deprecated, stop using it.

Comment: You in windows right? Use `CreateDirectory` from `windows.h` and `dirname` is uninitialized.

Comment: BTW don't use `gets`, it's an outdated and dangerous function.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271990/how-to-create-a-folder-in-c-need-to-run-on-both-linux-and-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 void create_folder() {
   int check;
   char dirname[128];
   clrscr();
   printf("Enter a directory path and name to create a folder (C:/name):");
   fgets(dirname, sizeof(dirname), stdin);
   check = mkdir(dirname);

   if (!check)
     printf("Folder created\n");

   else {
     printf("Unable to create folder\n");
     exit(1);
   }
   getch();
   system("dir/p");
   getch();
 }
```

Your dirname string was unallocated, use a char array instead.

Comment: You must strip the trailing newline stored into `dirname` by `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to allocate memory for `dirname`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dir.h>

#define SIZE 25      //Maximum Length of name of folder

void main() {
    int check;
    char *dirname;
    dirname=malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter a directory path and name to be created (C:/name):");
    gets(dirname);
    check = mkdir(dirname);
    free(dirname);
    if (!check)
        printf("Directory created\n");

    else
    {
        printf("Unable to create directory\n");
        exit(1);  
    } 
    getch();
    system("dir/p");
    getch();
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to free the memory allocated using malloc fo dirname

Comment: No matter how large you allocate `dirname`, `gets()` can still cause a buffer overflow.  Use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I copied from [Mahonri Moriancumer's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23272187/5595995):

```
void make_directory(const char* name) {
   #ifdef __linux__
       mkdir(name, 777); 
   #else
       _mkdir(name);
   #endif
}
```

Comment: `_mkdir` is specific to the Windows or MS/DOS operating systems, `mkdir` is a POSIX standard system call.  The `#ifdef` should be modified accordingly.