# How can I create folder under a given user in Windows?

Tags: c, filesystems

How can I create a file/folder in Windows using a C program under a given user?

For example, if I have to make something in Desktop "C:\Users(user)\Desktop"

I'm using a system call in C, so I have to substitute the user for the actual username, how can I do that?

`int b = 1; char mkdir[33] = "MKDIR Desktop\\"; sprintf(mkdir, "MKDIR Desktop\\%i", b); system(mkdir);`

But instead of creating a file at Desktop it continues in the current directory and creates a file called Desktop?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271990/how-to-create-a-folder-in-c-need-to-run-on-both-linux-and-windows/23272187#23272187

Answer (score 0):

> What can I make if I have to go to a directory within one of the users in C?

The C language standard (read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then e.g. [n2126](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf)) does not know about directories, so you need to use some operating system specific API. See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website.

For Linux (or POSIX), read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then about [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and use [mkdir(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html)

For Windows, read more about the [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/) and the [directory management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/directory-management-reference).

You might use [system](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) with some `MKDIR` operating system specific command, but that is less efficient (and you still need to handle failure).

### Take inspiration from existing open source code.

(e.g. [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/))

You could use cross-platform opensource libraries like [GTK](https://gtk.org/) and [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/).

> ```
>    sprintf(mkdir, "MKDIR Desktop\\%i", b);
> ```

Your use of [sprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is dangerous because of potential [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Consider using `snprintf`.